# Ubuntu 22.04 - after update from 20.04 the system starts in tty1 no xorg present

Tags: xorg, 22.04, do-release-upgrade

when I tried to upgrade from 20.04 -> 22.04 (it already told me there is an avail update) .. it ended up in this weird blank screen

[image]

If I go to the cli and try

```
startx
```

It will go back to the same window ...

any idea how to fix it? I dunno where to look for errors :( If there is more info needed, I will provide of course

EDIT:  checked the DMESG

```
$: dmesg --level=emerg,alert,crit,err

[    0.131906] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[    0.488306] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[    0.488323] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR01._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.488373] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[    0.488385] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR02._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.488432] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[    0.488443] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR03._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.488488] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[    0.488499] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR04._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.488545] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[    0.488556] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR05._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    2.618471] usbhid 1-5:1.1: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
[    7.306309] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
[   14.626061] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
[   19.315736] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
```

and when running

```
$: startx -- -logverbose 6 :2
```

I am getting

```
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.3
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operation System: Linux XXXX 5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 18:03:24 UTC 2022 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic root=UUIDxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ro quiet splach vt.handoff=7
xorg-server 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.1 
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
...

Waiting for X server to begin accepting connections ....
(II) AIGLX:Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch...
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0) Closing log file.

xinit: server error
```

here is the /var/log/Xorg.O.log >> https://pastebin.com/JmRghznh

Comment: You might have a broken upgrade ... Did you try to upgrade afterwords with `sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: If for any reason you can't do `sudo apt upgrade` from your current installation, then you can try from a live USB as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238393/968501) ... You can also try from the [recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501)

Comment: Try to find out Intel Software Guard Extension (SGX) in BIOS security section and enable it

Comment: After `startx` fails take a peek into `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for detailed errors

Comment: @Raffa `sudo apt upgrade` works fine but doesn't solve anything

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix pasted the log in the original post (pastebin)

Comment: Please check your repository sources list are correct for your release  … Information here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1305148

Comment: xprg/-/;pg says there is no screen layout., Can you report `cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf`? **NOTE:** `X` is a capital. Also `xorg.conf` may be in a user directory as well.

Comment: well I ended up reinstalling the server ... luckily the partitioning I had was fine so I only had to reconfigure all services but data were safe ..thx for the help

Answer (score 3):

Check if the ubuntu-desktop package is installed.

`apt search ubuntu-desktop`

In my case, it was removed during release upgrade and I had to reinstall it manually.

`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

It may be necessary to issue `sudo apt update` once before trying install or search for the package, to retrieve/update information about available packages.

If `apt` still can't locate the package, or if `sudo apt update` fails, check whether your source repositories are configured correctly. You can learn about how to do it by reading the man page `man sources.list`.
The configuration file is `/etc/apt/sources.list` and possibly similar files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.
Or you try one of the solutions from this question: [unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)

Also, make sure that you have a working internet connection. :-)

Finally, not really solving the problem though, you can reinstall the latest version of Ubuntu from a live image. It is possible to do so without losing the files in your home folder, even if you don't have a separate partition for `/home`. Refer to [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation).
Although this will not provide a conclusive answer to your question and thus not 'solve' your problem in particular, it *could* be a way/the easiest way to re-acquire a working system. Good luck!

Comment: no package found :( when tried installing it `Unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @Raffa: Absolutely right, I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

**Check for default display manager**

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/sbin/gdm3
```

*Now, check if `gdm3` is installed.*

**Run install of `gdm3` as default display manager**

```
sudo apt install gdm3
```

**Next run the `ubuntu-desktop` install to get the default ubuntu environment settings**

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

*Note: make sure `ubuntu-dekstop` installs correctly without any errors.*

**Next run the following `systemctl` commands to set reload everytime on boot**

```
sudo systemctl isolate graphical
sudo systemctl set-default graphical
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user
sudo systemctl start gdm3
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

**Reboot**

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I was able to get back my GUI login and final Ubuntu Jammy UI window after running these commands. Facing some issues with audio thought, apart from that, everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't `ubuntu 22.04` switch from `xorg` to `wayland` ?!

If that is so, it does not explain what went wrong with your release upgrade. However, you might be looking at the wrong place to fix your windowing system.

This here might also have a solution for you:
[Windowing doesn't start and can't be started after upgrade to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423434/windowing-doesnt-start-and-cant-be-started-after-upgrade-to-22-04)

Comment: yeah I saw the discussion but that didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo systemctl enable gdm3
sudo systemctl start gdm3
```

If that fails then you need to try running wayland:

`dbus-run-session -- gnome-shell --display-server --wayland`

Lastly, you can switch to different ttys using

`CTRL+ALT+F2`

where the number corresponds to the tty number. If you insist on using xorg then you can try running `startx` in a diffetent `tty console`

Comment: there is not `/lib/systemd/system/gdm3.service` at all  :( and for the dbus >> `dbus-run-session: failed to exec 'gnome-shell': No such file or directory`